# jQuery Horizontal Scrolling (click and animate)

Tags: jquery, scroll, click, jquery-animate

I have a series of divs floating to infinity in a horizontal line. I have a fixed width div container them, overflow:hidden. Ultimately, I'd like to press divs/buttons on left and right to scroll through the items (vs. using scrollbar).

I am having trouble getting .animate() to work. I want each click to move the items within the list over.

It should work similar to Amazons "Customers Who Bought This Item Also Bought" list that you can scroll through in the same manner. I was tempted to try using .mousedown and have it move while holding (similar to true scrolling) but want do this easier approach first.

Here is the fiddle and code:

http://jsfiddle.net/stfzy/16/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="arrowL">
</div>
<div id="arrowR">
</div>
<div id="list-container">
    <div class='list'>
        <div class='item'>
        </div>
        <div class='item'>
        </div>
        <div class='item'>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 #container{
width:340px;
    height:50px;
}

#list-container {
overflow:hidden;    
width: 300px;  
float:left;    
}

.list{
    background:grey;
min-width:700px;
    float:left;
}


#arrowR{
background:yellow;
    width:20px;
    height:50px;
    float:right;
    cursor:pointer;
}


#arrowL{
background:yellow;
    width:20px;
    height:50px;
    float:left;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.item{
    background:green;
width:140px;
    height:40px;
    margin:5px;
    float:left;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('div#arrowR').click(function(){

        $('div.item').animate({'left':'-=300px'});

    });

    $('div#arrowR').click(function(){

        $('div.item').animate({'left':'+=300px'});

    });

});
```

Any and all help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add `position:relative` to `.item`, like so:

```
.item{
    background:green;
    width:140px;
    height:40px;
    margin:5px;
    float:left;
    position:relative; /* Put me here! */
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/mattblancarte/stfzy/21/

There are a few more bugs in your setup, but this should get you unstuck. :)

Edit::

Here is a quick solution to solve the bug where the list will slide too far in either direction:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $item = $('div.item'), //Cache your DOM selector
        visible = 2, //Set the number of items that will be visible
        index = 0, //Starting index
        endIndex = ( $item.length / visible ) - 1; //End index (NOTE:: Requires visible to be a factor of $item.length... You can improve this by rounding...)

    $('div#arrowR').click(function(){
        if(index < endIndex ){
          index++;
          $item.animate({'left':'-=300px'});
        }
    });

    $('div#arrowL').click(function(){
        if(index > 0){
          index--;            
          $item.animate({'left':'+=300px'});
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Awesome! And I see what you mean about more bugs... I assume you are referring to the fact that my list has a start and end. However, it needs to loop to work effectively. Hmmm... time to figure that one out. Thanks again.

Comment: Or maybe I'll cause the arrow buttons to disable when there is no more content... probably a better option.

Comment: @jstacks Happy to help! If you haven't already figured it out, you can track the position of the scroll by assigning a start index of 0 and then calculate a max index based on how many items are within the list. If you hit the min, disable the left button. If you hit the max, disable the right button. Hope that makes sense! That's not the only way to go about it, but it's one solution. :)

Comment: I'm not too good with jQuery so I had yet to figure it out. That's really helpful, thanks! Would you happen to be able to refer me to documentation on indexing? I'm not really sure how that works. Also, what would be the approach for having it loop back to the first set? Not sure if it's significantly more difficult, but curious as to how both options end up looking...

Comment: @jstacks No worries. There really isn't any documentation on how to do this. You might find it by googling, but I just went ahead and built out a solution for you. [Check out this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattblancarte/stfzy/21/). Let me know if you have any questions about how it works!

Comment: Wow. Thank you. Those notes help tremendously too, so I see what's going on. :)

Comment: @jstacks Excellent! Glad I could help. The only little bit I left out there is properly accounting for "n" list items when calculating the endIndex. I'll let you figure that out... (Hint: [Check out some of the vanilla JS Math object methods](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/mathfunc.htm))

Comment: If you don't want to keep track of indexes, you could also use: if (($('div.box:last').width() + $('div.box:last').offset().left) < ($('#wrapper').width() + $('#wrapper').offset().left)) then disable the right button. Else similarly disable the left button with first instead of last. Of course a lot of refactoring in terms of caching and optimization is possible.