# how to create a sideways photo clickable jquery slideshow

Tags: jquery, slideshow

i have googled a lot to create a slideshow like this.. but no luck..

http://www.polygon.com/2013/2/21/4014286/infamous-second-son-playstation4-gallery#!/3934479 (scroll the page to see the slideshow)

can somebody help me on this.. thanx..

i would like it to be responsive too

i searched your site and what I found was this

[jQuery Horizontal Scrolling (click and animate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13438135/jquery-horizontal-scrolling-click-and-animate)

here you have given an arrow to click, but i want the next or previous image to be clicked to go respective image..

i am new to php programming and knows a little jquery and javascript..

any help would be appriciated.. thankx..

Comment: Instead of adding `SOLVED` tag; just select the correct answer by pressing the checkmark symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i searched and come across with this best suitable result for you

Demo:
[Demo of this Lib](http://bartaz.github.com/impress.js/#/bored)

Source:[source and documentation for Lib](https://github.com/bartaz/impress.js/)

I hope this will answer your question :)

Comment: sorry to interrupt again.. i couldn't implement it.. maybe the code is too huge for me.. could you please show me a little demo at http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: if you have downloaded demo from the link i mentioned in source then open the index.html in editor and there you can see there are alot of comments, which clearly defines how it works

Comment: if this answers your question please mark it. this will help others who will read this thread.